# Update GridView color without refreshing in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm confused about how can I update the background item color of my GridView without reloading the activity, the background color of the item is based on the database SQLite status. Currently, I reload the activity using intent in order to update the `GridView` background color, but I think there's another way using `notifyDataSetChanged();` whenever I click the exclude button it will change the color or status of the `grid view`, It is very helpful for me if someone finds out this problem.

[image]

```
    ArrayList<Inventory> list = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new InventoryListAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_inventory_items, list);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            Long l= new Long(id);
            int i=l.intValue();

            if (status==0){DialogStatus ="Include";}else{DialogStatus ="Exclude";}
            new SweetAlertDialog(InventoryList.this, SweetAlertDialog.WARNING_TYPE)
                    .setTitleText("Are you sure?")
                    .setContentText("Please choose corresponding action")
                    .setConfirmText("Update")
                    .setCancelText(DialogStatus)
                    .showCancelButton(true)

                    .setCancelClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {
                                sqLiteHelper.excludeData(i,status); //change status of the item

                                //here I tried to reload again the activity using intent
                                // I think it is possible in `notifyDataSetChanged();`


                                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),InventoryList.class);
                                in.putExtra("ExcludeInclude", DialogStatus);
                                startActivity(in);
                                finish();
                        }
                    }).show();
                }
            });
```

**Update**

```
import com.example.cashgrantsmobile.Database.SQLiteHelper;
public static SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;

ArrayList<Inventory>  list = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new InventoryListAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_inventory_items, list);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {

            Long l= new Long(id);
            int i=l.intValue();
            new SweetAlertDialog(InventoryList.this, SweetAlertDialog.WARNING_TYPE)
                    .setTitleText("Are you sure?")
                    .setContentText("Please choose corresponding action")
                    .setConfirmText("Update")
                    .setCancelText(DialogStatus)
                    .showCancelButton(true)
                    .setCancelClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {

                                sqLiteHelper.excludeData(i,status);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }).show();
                }
            });
```

**SqliteHelper**

```
    public void excludeData(int i, int status) {
    if (status == 0){status =1;}
    else {status =0;}
    int idd = i+1;
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    String sql = "UPDATE CgList SET card_scanning_status = ?,card_scanning_status = ? WHERE id = ? ";
    SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(sql);
    statement.bindLong(1, 0);
    statement.bindLong(2, status);
    statement.bindLong(3, idd);
    statement.execute();
    database.close();
}
```

**Inventory List class** The triggering part is more likely in the sweet alert

```
public class InventoryListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   
        private Context context;
        private  int layout;
        private ArrayList<Inventory> inventoryList;
        String DarkModeStatus;
    
        public InventoryListAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<Inventory> foodsList) {
            this.context = context;
            this.layout = layout;
            this.inventoryList = foodsList;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return inventoryList.size();
        }
    
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return inventoryList.get(position);
        }
    
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
    
        private class ViewHolder{
            ImageView imageView, mPreviewCashCard;
            TextView txtName, txtPrice, txtSeriesNo;
        }
    
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            Cursor cursor = MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT id,status FROM DarkMode");
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                DarkModeStatus = cursor.getString(1);
            }
    
            View row = view;
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    
            if(row == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = inflater.inflate(layout, null);
                holder.txtName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
                holder.txtPrice = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
                holder.txtSeriesNo = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtSeriesNumber);
                holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgFood);
                holder.mPreviewCashCard = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgId);
                row.setTag(holder);
            }
            else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
            }
            Inventory inventory = inventoryList.get(position);
            holder.txtName.setText(inventory.getName());
            holder.txtPrice.setText(inventory.getPrice());
            holder.txtSeriesNo.setText(inventory.getSeriesNumber());
            int status = inventory.getStatus();
            if (status==0 && DarkModeStatus.matches("false")){
                  //exclude and white
                row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FEF8DD")); //
            }
            else if(status==0 && DarkModeStatus.matches("true")){
                //exclude and dark
                row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#282828"));
            }
            else if (status==1 && DarkModeStatus.matches("false")) {
                //include and white
                row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F7F7FA")); // white background color you are using
            }
            else if (status==1 && DarkModeStatus.matches("true")) {
                //include and white
                row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#252C4B")); // white background color you are using
            }
    
            byte[] CashCardImage = inventory.getImage();
            byte[] idImage = inventory.getIdImage();
            if(CashCardImage.length > 1)
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(CashCardImage, 0, CashCardImage.length);
                holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            else{
                holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_image);
            }
            if(idImage.length > 1)
            {
                Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(idImage, 0, idImage.length);
                holder.mPreviewCashCard.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);
            }
            else{
                holder.mPreviewCashCard.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_image);
            }
            return row;
        }
    }

**Inventory List class**

    public class InventoryList extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridView gridView;
    ArrayList<Inventory> list;
    InventoryListAdapter adapter = null;
    String cashCardNumber;
    private Toolbar mToolbars;
    int status;
    byte[] id_image;
    String DialogStatus;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inventory_list);
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        mToolbars = findViewById(R.id.mainToolbar);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String value = extras.getString("ExcludeInclude");
            Toasty.success(this,value+"d", Toasty.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbars);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Inventory List");
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new InventoryListAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_inventory_items, list);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {

                Long l= new Long(id);
                int i=l.intValue();
                int stats = i+1;

                Cursor cursor = MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT id,id_image,card_scanning_status FROM CgList WHERE id ="+stats);
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    id_image = cursor.getBlob(1);
                    status = cursor.getInt(2);
                }

                if (status==0){DialogStatus ="Include";}else{DialogStatus ="Exclude";}
                new SweetAlertDialog(InventoryList.this, SweetAlertDialog.WARNING_TYPE)
                        .setTitleText("Are you sure?")
                        .setContentText("Please choose corresponding action")
                        .setConfirmText("Update")
                        .setCancelText(DialogStatus)
                        .showCancelButton(true)
                        .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {
                                ScannedDetails.scanned = false;
                                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScannedDetails.class);

                                if (id_image.length ==1){
                                    in.putExtra("updateData", i);
                                    in.putExtra("EmptyImageView","triggerEvent");
                                }
                                else{
                                    in.putExtra("updateData", i);
                                }
                                startActivity(in);
                            }
                        })
                        .setCancelClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {
                                if (id_image.length ==1){
                                    Toasty.error(getApplicationContext(),"Update data first ", Toasty.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                else{
                                    sqLiteHelper.excludeData(i,status);
                                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InventoryList.class);
                                    in.putExtra("ExcludeInclude", DialogStatus);
                                    startActivity(in);
                                    finish();

                                }
                            }
                        }).show();
                    }
                });


        try {
            Field field = CursorWindow.class.getDeclaredField("sCursorWindowSize");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(null, 100 * 1024 * 1024); //the 100MB is the new size
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            Cursor cursor = sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT id,cash_card_actual_no,hh_number,series_number,cc_image, id_image, cash_card_scanned_no, card_scanning_status FROM CgList");
            list.clear();
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                int id = cursor.getInt(0);
                if (cursor.getString(1).matches("")){
                    cashCardNumber = cursor.getString(6);
                }
                else{
                    cashCardNumber = cursor.getString(1);
                }
                String hhNumber = cursor.getString(2);
                String seriesNumber = cursor.getString(3);
                byte[] CashCardImage = cursor.getBlob(4);
                byte[] idImage = cursor.getBlob(5);
                int status = cursor.getInt(7);
                list.add(new Inventory(cashCardNumber, hhNumber,seriesNumber, CashCardImage, idImage,status, id));

            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error: "+ e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(InventoryList.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why one would want to reload an activity? I mean what reloading activity means? You have a dataset, on the back end (database) and it feeds your front end (gridview) via an adapter. When you want to change the displayig dataset, you wanna query new dataset, then set the list of the adapter class, and finally call `notifyDataSetChanged`. That's it! And you can put conditions according the data count to modify the background color. The code snippet you provide does not help to figure out your issues. Add all related code.

Comment: @Kozmotronik thanks for your response, I added the code above which I've tried notifyDataSetChanged but it didn't work.

Comment: @CarlJade please add the code where you are initializing list using sqlitehelper.

Comment: @DeePanShu Thanks for your response I just updated the code above which initiliaze sqlitehelper and I've also added the sqlitehelper.exclude method which changes after updating item from `gridview` hope it helps me

Comment: @CarlJade I don't see the code where you reference or bind the query result with your list? You execute the query then what happens? Your code doesn't seem to get the query results and update its content. How the `list` variable refers to the executed query? Somethings missing in that code. You did not add  the whole activity code so we can track your steps and diagnose the missing part. Go ahead and add the whole activity code.

Comment: @Kozmotronik Sorry I update my code above which contains getView of my GridView, it is the code you wanted?

Comment: @CarlJade no my friend, I must see the whole `InventoryList.class` implementation. Because the problem is very likely in that class.

Comment: @Kozmotronik Thanks for the response, I added my whole InventoryList class above hope it can helps

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `notifyDataSetChanged` you might want to use `DiffUtil` in terms of performance since it is not needed to redraw every row.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to restart the whole activity to load new data from the database. This is not the way how it's done. What you're doing here:

```java
try {
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT id,cash_card_actual_no,hh_number,series_number,cc_image, id_image, cash_card_scanned_no, card_scanning_status FROM CgList");
    list.clear();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(0);
        if (cursor.getString(1).matches("")){
            cashCardNumber = cursor.getString(6);
        }
        else{
            cashCardNumber = cursor.getString(1);
        }
        String hhNumber = cursor.getString(2);
        String seriesNumber = cursor.getString(3);
        byte[] CashCardImage = cursor.getBlob(4);
        byte[] idImage = cursor.getBlob(5);
        int status = cursor.getInt(7);
        list.add(new Inventory(cashCardNumber, hhNumber,seriesNumber, CashCardImage, idImage,status, id));

    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
catch (Exception e){
    Log.d(TAG, "Error: "+ e);
}
```

move this snippet to a background thread. So when you're done with the query reference the new query to the activity's list.

```java
public class InventoryList extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridView gridView;
    ArrayList<Inventory> list;
    InventoryListAdapter adapter = null;
    String cashCardNumber;
    private Toolbar mToolbars;
    int status;
    byte[] id_image;
    String DialogStatus;
    /// UI handler
    private Handler hmain = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    /// Background handler for disk operations
    private Handler hdisk;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inventory_list);
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        mToolbars = findViewById(R.id.mainToolbar);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String value = extras.getString("ExcludeInclude");
            Toasty.success(this,value+"d", Toasty.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbars);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Inventory List");
        list = new ArrayList<>();

        /// Intialize the handler and its thread
        HandlerThread htdisk = new HandlerThread(
                "com.yourAppName.inventoryList.diskio",
                Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_LESS_FAVORABLE
        );
        htdisk.setDaemon(true);
        htdisk.start();
        hdisk = new Handler(htdisk.getLooper());

        adapter = new InventoryListAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_inventory_items, list);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {

                Long l= new Long(id);
                int i=l.intValue();
                int stats = i+1;

                Cursor cursor = MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT id,id_image,card_scanning_status FROM CgList WHERE id ="+stats);
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    id_image = cursor.getBlob(1);
                    status = cursor.getInt(2);
                }

                if (status==0){DialogStatus ="Include";}else{DialogStatus ="Exclude";}
                new SweetAlertDialog(InventoryList.this, SweetAlertDialog.WARNING_TYPE)
                        .setTitleText("Are you sure?")
                        .setContentText("Please choose corresponding action")
                        .setConfirmText("Update")
                        .setCancelText(DialogStatus)
                        .showCancelButton(true)
                        .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {
                                ScannedDetails.scanned = false;
                                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScannedDetails.class);

                                if (id_image.length ==1){
                                    in.putExtra("updateData", i);
                                    in.putExtra("EmptyImageView","triggerEvent");
                                }
                                else{
                                    in.putExtra("updateData", i);
                                }
                                startActivity(in);
                            }
                        })
                        .setCancelClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {
                                if (id_image.length ==1){
                                    Toasty.error(getApplicationContext(),"Update data first ", Toasty.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                else{
                                    excludeData(i, status); /// Exclude data in background
                                }
                            }
                        }).show();
                    }
                });


        try {
            Field field = CursorWindow.class.getDeclaredField("sCursorWindowSize");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(null, 100 * 1024 * 1024); //the 100MB is the new size
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(InventoryList.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private void initData() {

    }

    /// You can name it whatever you like
    private void excludeData(int i, int status) {
        // Change the color of the gridview's background here before entering the disk bg thread
        // TODO change the color of the gridview's background
        hdisk.post(() -> {
            // First exclude
            sqLiteHelper.excludeData(i,status);
            // Then query the new excluded dataset
            try {
            Cursor cursor = sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT id,cash_card_actual_no,hh_number,series_number,cc_image, id_image, cash_card_scanned_no, card_scanning_status FROM CgList");
            list.clear();
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                int id = cursor.getInt(0);
                if (cursor.getString(1).matches("")){
                    cashCardNumber = cursor.getString(6);
                }
                else{
                    cashCardNumber = cursor.getString(1);
                }
                String hhNumber = cursor.getString(2);
                String seriesNumber = cursor.getString(3);
                byte[] CashCardImage = cursor.getBlob(4);
                byte[] idImage = cursor.getBlob(5);
                int status = cursor.getInt(7);
                list.add(new Inventory(cashCardNumber, hhNumber,seriesNumber, CashCardImage, idImage,status, id));

            }
            /// When querying is done post the result to the ui
            hmain.post(() -> {
                adapter.setList(list); // no need to notify since it is done within the method.
                // If you wanna change the gridview's color back do it here after notifying the adapter
                // TODO change the gridview's bg color back if needed
            });

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error: "+ e);
        }
        });
    }
}
```

I have modified your code in a text editor hence couldn't test it. But the purpose is showing you the data refreshing logic without restarting the whole activity. Try this logic and let me know if you get any compile time or runtime errors.

**Update for Adapter**

```java
public class InventoryListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   
    private Context context;
    private  int layout;
    private ArrayList<Inventory> inventoryList;
    String DarkModeStatus;

    public InventoryListAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<Inventory> foodsList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.inventoryList = foodsList;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return inventoryList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return inventoryList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        ImageView imageView, mPreviewCashCard;
        TextView txtName, txtPrice, txtSeriesNo;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        Cursor cursor = MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT id,status FROM DarkMode");
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            DarkModeStatus = cursor.getString(1);
        }

        View row = view;
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        if(row == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(layout, null);
            holder.txtName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            holder.txtPrice = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
            holder.txtSeriesNo = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtSeriesNumber);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgFood);
            holder.mPreviewCashCard = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgId);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        Inventory inventory = inventoryList.get(position);
        holder.txtName.setText(inventory.getName());
        holder.txtPrice.setText(inventory.getPrice());
        holder.txtSeriesNo.setText(inventory.getSeriesNumber());
        int status = inventory.getStatus();
        if (status==0 && DarkModeStatus.matches("false")){
                //exclude and white
            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FEF8DD")); //
        }
        else if(status==0 && DarkModeStatus.matches("true")){
            //exclude and dark
            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#282828"));
        }
        else if (status==1 && DarkModeStatus.matches("false")) {
            //include and white
            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F7F7FA")); // white background color you are using
        }
        else if (status==1 && DarkModeStatus.matches("true")) {
            //include and white
            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#252C4B")); // white background color you are using
        }

        byte[] CashCardImage = inventory.getImage();
        byte[] idImage = inventory.getIdImage();
        if(CashCardImage.length > 1)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(CashCardImage, 0, CashCardImage.length);
            holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        else{
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_image);
        }
        if(idImage.length > 1)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(idImage, 0, idImage.length);
            holder.mPreviewCashCard.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);
        }
        else{
            holder.mPreviewCashCard.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_image);
        }
        return row;
    }
    
    /// Added list setter
    public void setList(List<Inventory> newInventoryList) {
        inventoryList.clear();
        inventoryList.addAll(newInventoryList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I have encountered an error with this image [Image_Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdT9W.png)  `THREAD_PRIORITY_LESS_FAVORABLE` do you know the cause of this error?

Comment: import Process class `import android.os.Process;`

Comment: thanks for your response but I'm confused under `private excludeData()` It has an error should I make it `private void excludeData(int i)` instead? [errorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8L3y.png), but Even I tried and changed that, the list didn't show, there's no list display, do have any idea? :(

Comment: Oh, I see. I have fixed the errors and updated the code. Please compile it again and let me know the result.

Comment: `Even I tried and changed that, the list didn't show, there's no list display, do have any idea?` Yes, I guess this happens when we set the list only in the activity but not in the adapter. You need to add a public method like setLİst() and call it everytime the list in the activity is changed.

Comment: @CarlJade I have updated the code as per your feedback. Now the list must be updated when you call exclude.

Comment: How can I show the list when going to the activity InventoryList? I tried adding and putting `adapter.setList(list);` inside `oncreate()` of the `InventoryList` but it didn't show the list I just add it like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znqF1.png) :(

Comment: The adaptor will not know when the list has changed. You must call `setList()` method of the adapter whenever you query your data in the `list`. **There will be no list shown** unless you query data from your database, then add it to your `list`, and finally after finishing creating the `list` you call `setList()` and new data will show up in the UI.

Comment: Thanks for your response but for clarification, The query item list not showing in the activity because the query was put inside `excludedata` method so the question is I just need to make another function that queries the list and put it inside `onCreate` ? and remove the query inside `excludeData` since it is redundant , am I right?

Comment: Well, not exactly if you refer to `excludeData` method of the **Activity**. The query must be there after changing the data set by calling `sqLiteHelper.excludeData`, hence what we want to show in the activity's list. What you put inside the `onCreate` must be one time initialization of the activity. So in `onCreate` you should query the data once before initializing the activity and for the rest you must query the data everytime the listed content want to be changed by the user within the same activity, and without restartin the whole activity. Hope that I could explain it well :) .